# "Matchmaking website" for project-specific mathematical collaborations

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, career

It seems that even in the age of Internet, most mathematical collaborations are born (and pursued) off-line.

> However, I wonder if there exists a "matchmaking website" for mathematical collaboration on specific projects.

I'm thinking of MathOverflow meets Upwork, which may turn out to be very useful in a variety of circumstances (and indeed, if there is no such website, it could be something worth thinking about).

Comment: There are polymath projects where a wiki is used to collect and organize work.  There is MathOverflow where various specific topics are presented and those who wish to pursue further can use MathOverflow or email or some other means. (I did this last year with Jose Brox.) There are blogs where commentary and ideas are solicited with links to Github and other repositories of proofs, programs, and data.  What would be lacking from a combination of these methods for doing a collaboration? Use a web search to find projects.  Gerhard "Let's Get Together On This" Paseman, 2019.01.06.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman A specifically dedicated space for systematic usage is precisely what is lacking (as opposed to various tiny scattered places).

Comment: "Hmm, Smith has expertise in Lie groups, viscosity methods, and KPZ universality, which are just what this project needs.  But he puts $2\pi$ in the exponent when writing a Fourier transform? Swipe left."

Comment: IMO such a website should not be limited to collaboration in only mathematics; rather it should be a matchmaking in any math, sci, or engineering projects, with math collab being one of the collab sister sites, much like MO is one of several Stack Exchange sister sites. That way collab can extend to other areas as well.

Comment: @Michael I agree. Organizing a StackExchange type network to foster project specific collaborations instead of Q&A would seem a useful proposal.